# What makes Espresso so fast?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've been running some performance tests on various Ruby frameworks and turns out Espresso is much faster than any out there. I've a large codebase written in Sinatra and would love to speed the app up and was wondering if it was possible to somehow extract the underlying engine of Espresso and plug it in into Sinatra. Has anyone thought about this? I know they're both based on Rack, so what really explains the difference in performance?

Comment: If you look here: https://github.com/espresso/espresso you will see a nice comparison between frameworks. In short (and ignoring much important detail): If your response times (measured at the server) from your Sinatra app are < 10ms on average, then moving to Espresso could bring benefits. If they are 20ms or higher, you are unlikely to see much return on any work put in to change framework. Yes it's faster, but you'll get much more looking at your database or other I/O limitations.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a quick look at Espresso, I would say it is faster due to its simplicity rather than any re-usable deeper "engine".

Web services running under Sinatra or Rails use slightly more abstraction when processing and preparing request data, resulting in a few more method calls, and this adds overhead when compared to the simpler framework of Espresso.

A transfer from Sinatra to Espresso would be a conversion to use Espresso's DSL, which exposes methods more directly than Sinatra's block-based routing. You cannot hook Sinatra routes to Espresso easily, nor would it be likely to result in a speed increase if you managed to do so. That's because you would still end up using Sintatra's route handling, which is a major cause of the speed difference.

In practice, the speed difference between is only a problem if you are trying to create a very highly-performing service with sub-10ms response times. That requires other parts of the system to be highly optimised too, not just the request handling framework, which in practice consumes only a small percentage of the total response time from the server in most applications.

Comment: +1 Most of my calls are sub-10ms and thus my curiosity. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Neil's answer is comprehensive enough.

I only can add that Espresso, by design, is doing most of routing stuff at load time.

And at runtime it is passing request directly into matched action, which is a Ruby method.

Also, Espresso is using own URL mapper which is optimized under the specific needs.

Not sure about using Espresso's engine within Sinatra.

Could be easier to find a "easy" way to convert Sinatra's DSL into Ruby methods...